# Is it possible to set the terminals 'default directory' to desktop?

Tags: bash, terminal, home

For example, every time I open the terminal, `Ctrl Alt T` or actually cliking it, it's directory is `/home/bob`

I want it to be `home/bob/desktop`. How do I make this the "default" opening directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add and `cd desktop` at the end of your `.bashrc`; this way every time you open a new terminal, it will redirect you to your desired directory.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add a `cd ~/desktop` command to the end of your shell's initialization script – in this case, `~/.bashrc`.

There are some other suggestions [here](https://superuser.com/a/283871/109989), depending on what environment you're using (though you may have to implement them slightly differently, as that's targeted at `urxvt`). These are:

- Use an "Open in Terminal" shortcut (if your desktop environment provides) on the Desktop itself
- Alter the keyboard shortcut to add a relevant parameter to your terminal emulator, such as:
  `gnome-terminal --working-directory=$HOME/desktop`